# Incorrect initial position with makeSceneTransitionAnimation

Tags: java, android, animation, android-activity, material-design

I'm testing out with `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation` to create a simple transition with 2 shared views between activities.

The gray "Image placeholder" and the title are marked as shared and passed to `.makeSceneTransitionAnimation`:

[image]

Notice how both of them start off at a position slightly lower: (the first frame of the transition is shown)
[image]

Why did that happen? What would be a possible solution? It is weird how it only happens when I go from the list (a `RecyclerView`) to the detail page. The error distance is exactly the height of the action bar, therefore I suspect the issue might be related to it.

Comment: Are you found the answer?...i have the same :(

Comment: @MahdiAstanei Unfortunately no, I haven't.